# How to search any query using Overpass API

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, nominatim, overpass-turbo

Nominatim API can accept query without adding any *name*, *class*, *type*, *city*, *amenity* and so on to the request:

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=MacDonald&format=json

How to do the same using Overpass API?

**Updated**

it should clear now what I'm asking (I want to implement the search function which is similar to Google Maps search function)

Comment: It's not clear from your question, which tags you want to filter, and if you're looking for nodes, ways or relations. Remember that you need to provide **exact** OSM tags to Overpass API, while Nominatim has a bit of abstraction. Also, please edit the title of your question, it has nothing to do with what you want to do.

Comment: @mmd I replaced query with `MacDonald`

Comment: Still not clear. Again, you need to work out a set of OSM tags you're interested in and use them as part of your query . Free-style and in particular any kind of fuzzy search is **not** supported by Overpass API. I think you're looking for some other tool here.

Comment: @mmd so OpenStreeMap doesn't have anything like Google Maps search?

Comment: OpenStreetMap is essentially an Open Data project, you can take the raw data and do whatever you want with it (within the ODbL license), set up your own search engine on it, etc.

Comment: @mmd I understand but I believed some big projects like nominatim, overpass did something like this already... Nominatim can return quite normal results when you request something like *nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=place name 56.70400775 -3.7367683&format=json* (adding lat and lng to your query) but it returns only some of the nearest places for that location. Google Maps returns from the nearest to the farthest (you can infinitely scroll down from the nearest places to the farthest through search results)

Comment: If you want tool that will get word/sentence and interpret its meaning then Overpass API is not sufficient. https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/Wizard is closer to that.

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny any example. From wiki I see it still expects you to set `tourism==query`, `amenity==query` and so on

Answer (score 1):

Just query for all nodes within a bounding box and perform a recurse up to get their ways, too.

Query:

```
[out:xml];
(
  node(51.99, 7.99, 52.0, 8.0);
  <;
);
out meta;
```

Data:
https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=%5Bout%3Axml%5D%3B%0A%28%0A%20%20node%2851.99%2C%207.99%2C%2052.0%2C%208.0%29%3B%0A%20%20%3C%3B%0A%29%3B%0Aout%20meta%3B

Example at overpass-turbo:
https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/DJK

Comment: I would like to find places around my location using any query

Comment: Then just modify the bounding box coordinates to match your location.

Comment: what about next request but without using amenity? https://www.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json][timeout:25];nwr(around:1000,47.842238,35.105437)["amenity"="school"];out%20center;["amenity"="school"];out%20center;

Comment: though I still don't understand why I can't set some query keywords to filter out places? using such query with `around` or `bounding box` (node) will return a lot of data. I have to download it using 3G and filter out no needed places then..

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. Specifying "keywords to filter out places" is *the* typical use-case for Overpass API explained in every howto and the [Language Guide](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide). However you asked the exact opposite: How to query for *all* features. I've answered this question. How to query for specific features is already answered at various other places. What exactly is still unclear to you?

Comment: No I meant "any place name" (you need to replace it with something logic), for example you can search for "MacDonald"

Comment: how to do the next but with overpass? https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=MacDonald&format=json

Comment: Nominatim can return quite normal results when you request something like nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=place name 56.70400775 -3.7367683&format=json (adding lat and lng to your query) but it returns only some of the nearest places for that location. Google Maps returns from the nearest to the farthest (you can infinitely scroll down from the nearest places to the farthest through search results)

Comment: Do you understand now (I updated my question)?

Comment: @user924 Yes, and it is impossible to do that using just OverpassAPI

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny ok, thanks. Does some other projects/libraries based on OpenStreetMap can do it? Nominatim can return quite normal results when you request something like **nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=name 56.70400775 -3.7367683&format=json** (adding lat and lng to your query) but it returns only some of the nearest places for that location. Google Maps returns from the nearest to the farthest (you can infinitely scroll down from the nearest places to the farthest through search results)